# Extract "Initial Offering Price/Yield" from MSRB using rvest in R: return no result

Tags: r, rvest

[A Random Muni. Bond](http://emma.msrb.org/SecurityView/SecurityDetails.aspx?cusip=ABFC4F024F571C1A749967D611BFCB853)

I've used the SelectorGadget tool to determine the CSS selector, however, it returns no result.

`page = html("http://emma.msrb.org/SecurityView/SecurityDetails.aspx?cusip=ABFC4F024F571C1A749967D611BFCB853")`

`ipo=html_nodes(page,"#ctl00_mainContentArea_securityHeaderLabelsUserControl1_initialOfferingPriceDataLabel")`

Comment: Did you check the terms of use?

Comment: You are missing a `?` in your url after `aspx` I think ...

Comment: @Eugene Thank you for pointing that out...

Answer (score 1):

#### Problem

The MSRB site requires a new user to click YES on a disclosure, after which a cookie will be set to enable further use.

> I'm not sure how to get the cookie programmatically, but once you have it, the following works.

#### Solution given cookie

```
require(rvest)
require(httr)

url <- "http://emma.msrb.org/SecurityView/SecurityDetails.aspx?cusip=ABFC4F024F571C1A749967D611BFCB853"
cookie <- "BIGipServeremma.msrb.org=724100618.20480.0000; __utmt=1; __utma=247245968.167884672.1459959072.1459959072.1459959072.1; __utmb=247245968.1.10.1459959072; __utmc=247245968; __utmz=247245968.1459959072.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); Disclaimer2=Moodys"
selector.priceData <- "#ctl00_mainContentArea_securityHeaderLabelsUserControl1_initialOfferingPriceDataLabel"

page  <-  html_session( url, add_headers(Cookie=cookie) )
ipo <- html_nodes( page, selector.priceData) %>% 
       html_text
ipo

[1] "100"
```

Comment: That's the approach I used, but unfortunately it doesn't explain how to fetch the cookie.

Comment: Thank you!@JasonAizkalns @Eugene